# FileNet Social Collaboration - search by comments

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

We have social collaboration enabled on our FileNet system. I can add comment, tag, like and track how many times a document has been downloaded. These features are nice. When I tag a document, I can search documents by the tag text.

Ex: If I tag a document as say "test". I can user a search template to search for a document by its tag value i.e. test.

When I comment, I can't search document based on Comment Text.

Say I added a comment as "good doc". I can't search it by the text. Rather I need to provide an integer value like 1 search. Then search happens like "get all documents which has number of comments =1". I don't want this behavior instead I should be able to search on the comment text.

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use CBR on the property. [See how to enable CBR on a property](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/cbr/csscbr_property_cbrenabling.htm)

The property will then be full-text searchable using the CONTAINS statement, see [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/cbr/csscbr_cbrquery_introduction.htm).

Optionally (but i'm not sure as i've never personally used it) - the [satisfies operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm#SATISFIES%20Operator) might exactly what you're looking for according to the documentation.